# Can I call menu_rebuild() only for one module or specific hook_menu?

Tags: 7, routes

Is there a way to call menu_rebuild so it will only update items
in selected module and / or hook_menu ?

I need it to update links ( if they are already existing ) and add new
( if they are now ).

Don't want the menu_rebuild to clear the menu_router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that's what the function does. From Drupal docs:

> This function will clear and populate the {menu_router} table, add entries to {menu_links} for new router items, and then remove stale items from {menu_links}. If called from update.php or install.php, it will also schedule a call to itself on the first real page load from menu_execute_active_handler(), because the maintenance page environment is different and leaves stale data in the menu tables.

I guess you could try to reimplement the function into your own custom one and modify its source according to your needs. It looks like a lot of work though. You'd probably have to reimplement more functions.

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7

Comment: Yes. I thought of that...

Comment: The function does what it does @MichałPrzybyłowicz, you can always implement your own and call that instead, but the core function is all or nothing unfortunately

Comment: @MichałPrzybyłowicz To add to Clive's comment - core function  is opensource, so it should be pretty easy to copy it and change :)